# What does "use a shooter of whiskey" mean?

Tags: meaning

Does "a shooter of whiskey" mean a bottle of whiskey?

Why say "use" instead of "drink" or "have"?

Comment: You don't give any context, but if you heard someone say this (or saw it written down) it was probably from either a non-native speaker or someone with relatively unusual dialectal speech. Native speakers in general are far more likely to say something like *"I could use a **shot** of whiskey"* - meaning *"I want a small glass of whiskey"* (to steady my nerves, lift my spirits, give me some energy, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *shooter* is a small glass, usually 2cl or 4cl in size. (0.7 oz / 1.4 oz (UK))
Also known as *shot glas*

[image: Shooter (found via Google search for "shooter whiskey")]

As to the usage of *use*:

- Maybe it's about the effects of whiskey. They are wanted and the shooter is a mere tool
- Maybe the shooter isn't consumed at all, maybe it is *used* to drown a fly
- Maybe it's just the author making use of his power to choose words to his liking

Look at the context and you should be able to see what's happening.
(My guess: Someone drinks it.)

Comment: One other note: it's often referred to as a _shot of whiskey_.

Comment: What @J.R. said. Google Books has just [12 instances of "a shooter of whiskey"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+shooter+of+whiskey%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22a+shooter+of+whiskey%22&start=10&tbm=bks), and none at all for the variant spelling "whisky". But it claims tens of thousands of results for both variants with *"a **shot**"*. With the more typically American *a shot of **bourbon***, we're looking at 15,000 hits, compared to only 5 for *shooter*. So I would say the non-standard usage is effectively irrelevant to the needs of learners.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Irrelevant for future use, perhaps, but not irrelevant for understanding. One never knows where someone will stumble across one of those 5 uses. :^)

Comment: @J.R.: Interestingly, OED's first citation for **shot**: a dram of spirits is *1928 P. G. Wodehouse Good Morning, Bill!*, who's about as British as they come. The first relevant **shooter**: ***U.S. slang.*** A measure or drink of spirit, esp. whisky is given as *(1971 Car & Driver)*, where it says *He made his famous call for ‘shooters’. Now **in case you haven't heard**, a ‘shooter’ is a Turner variation of the word ‘shot’, as in a ‘shot of likker’* I for one had *not* heard until now, but I think I'd always have been able to guess the meaning from context and extrapolation.